# Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $filterProvider from myapp

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters

I am getting following error:

> ( Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $filterProvider from myapp) while using following code. Please help to solve it.
>
> Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $filterProvider from myapp
>          at angular.min.js:29

HTML---------------------

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js">`</script>
    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="WeatherCtrl">
        <h2>Weather in Salzburg, Austria</h2>
        <weather-icon cloudiness="{{ weather.clouds }}"></weather-icon>
        <h3>Current: {{ weather.temp.current | temp:2 }}</h3>
        min: {{ weather.temp.min | temp }}, max: {{ weather.temp.max | temp }}
    </div>
```

Source code (.js)-------------------

```
    'use strict';

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.factory('weatherService', function($http) {
    return { 
      getWeather: function() {
        var weather = { temp: {}, clouds: null };
        $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Salzburg,at&units=metric&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&APPID=f9dbd911bc01df1d9ce563b2ba4d3209').success(function(data) {
            if (data) {
                if (data.main) {
                    weather.temp.current = data.main.temp;
                    weather.temp.min = data.main.temp_min;
                    weather.temp.max = data.main.temp_max;
                }
                weather.clouds = data.clouds ? data.clouds.all : undefined;
            }
        });

        return weather;
      }
    }; 
});

myapp.filter('temp', function($filter) {
    return function(input, precision) {
        if (!precision) {
            precision = 1;
        }
        var numberFilter = $filter('number');
        return numberFilter(input, precision) + '\u00B0C';
    };
});

    myapp.controller('WeatherCtrl', function ($scope, weatherService) {
        $scope.weather = weatherService.getWeather();
    });

    myapp.directive('weatherIcon', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E', replace: true,
            scope: {
                cloudiness: '@'
            },
            controller: funct

ion($scope) {
                $scope.imgurl = function() {
                    var baseUrl = 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/weather/128/';
                    if ($scope.cloudiness < 20) {
                        return baseUrl + 'sunny.png';
                    } else if ($scope.cloudiness < 90) {
                       return baseUrl + 'partly_cloudy.png';
                    } else {
                        return baseUrl + 'cloudy.png';
                    }
                };
            },
            template: '<div style="float:left"><img ng-src="{{ imgurl() }}"></div>'
        };
    });
```

Comment: There is no issue !

Comment: @JyotiRajSharma If there is an issue, please use this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0amjqtpv/) and try to replicate the issue and share!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can inject $filter into a filter definition, like you do here: `myapp.filter('temp', function($filter)`

EDIT: It seems I'm incorrect, and you should be able to inject $filter in.

Comment: check documentation here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter
Make correction to your answer. $filter is a default angular service.